# Time-based Scaling Does Nothing - Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am able to set time-based scaling events but they do nothing. Is there another setting that takes precedence over time-based scaling?

[image: time-based scaling]

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying you want to scale up to 10 and scale down to 2 everyday at a specified time and that is not happening? How did you configure the "Recurrence" parameter. Did you use the web console or the API or the CLI or
ebextensions?

Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalingscheduledaction):

```
Recurrence
The frequency with which you want the scheduled action to occur. If you
do not specify a recurrence, then the scaling action will occur only
once, as specified by the StartTime.
```

Comment: That is correct, up to 10, down to 2, 4 times per day. The scaling is not happening. It is set to be recurring and it always shows the correct "next occurrence" but the scaling never happens. I configured this via the web console.